# What is the difference between JQuery and JQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery

I heard some people say simply JQuery while others JQuery Plugin, when I googled, I didn't really find anything explaining the difference, are they the same?

Comment: One is a JavaScript library, and the other is code written to use that JavaScript library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a collection of functions (usually called a framework or library) that makes javascript easier to write (for most people).

A jQuery plugin is some code that relies on jQuery to work.

So, if you use a jQuery plugin on your website, you will also need to include the jQuery framework, but no plugin is required for jQuery to work.